# SPARQL: How to obtain label in available languages if first option is not available

Tags: sparql, linked-data, wikidata

If a Wikidata resource returned by my query has no available label in the language I filtered for I obtained an empty cell.

```
SELECT *
WHERE
{
    ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256.
    ?country rdfs:label ?country_name
        FILTER(LANG(?country_name) = 'jbo').
}
```

[link](https://query.wikidata.org/#SELECT%20%2A%0AWHERE%0A%7B%0A%09%3Fcountry%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ6256.%0A%20%20%09%3Fcountry%20rdfs%3Alabel%20%3Fcountry_name%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20FILTER%28LANG%28%3Fcountry_name%29%20%3D%20%27jbo%27%29.%0A%7D)

How to request to have a label returned in one of any of the available languages if the first language fails?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, prefer **[langMatches](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-langMatches)** for checking language tags.  This is especially important in your case, since you might want, for instance, a label in English, and **langMatches(lang(?label), "en")** will find a label with the tag "en", or "en-GB", or "en-US", etc.  Those are regional variants for the language, and **langMatches** can help you find them.

### Updated Solution based on comments

@svick noticed in the comments that the original solution ends up with a row for each element in the Cartesian product of the English names with the non-English names.  You can avoid that by using a **select distinct**.  But there's really a better way:  just use the same variable in two **optional**s;  the first checks for an English label, and the second checks for non-English labels.  If the first succeeds, then the second never gets invoked.  That is, just do:

```sql
select ?country ?label {
   ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 
   optional { 
     ?country rdfs:label ?label
     filter langMatches(lang(?label), "en")
   }
   optional { 
     ?country rdfs:label ?label
   }
}
```

### Other options

- If you need to do any aggregation, you may find some help in [SPARQL filter language if possible in multiple value context](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30624189/1281433).
- If, after the first language, you still have preferences on the remaining languages, you may find the technique used in [Sparql multi lang data compression to one row](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21531063/1281433) helpful.

---

---

### Original Solution with COALESCE

After that, though, **[coalesce](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-coalesce)** will do what you want.  It takes a number of arguments, and returns the first one that has a value.   So, you can match the preferred language in an **optional** block, and any language in another, and coalesce the values:

```sql
select distinct ?country (coalesce(?enLabel, ?anyLabel) as ?label) {
   ?country wdt:P31 wd:Q6256 
   optional { 
     ?country rdfs:label ?enLabel
     filter langMatches(lang(?enLabel), "en")
   }
   optional { 
     ?country rdfs:label ?anyLabel
   }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't sound like a great solution to me. If the country label is available in 270 languages, out of which 3 are variants of English, this will return 810 results, all containing the same label (because the 3 English ones are the same). This is exactly what happens for Canada (add `bind (wd:Q16 as ?country)` to the query).

Comment: @svick Ah yes, that should be **select distinct**...  The other option (mentioned in one of the linked questions/answers) that's probably just as good, is to use two optionals that bind the same variable.  I've updated my answer with the better option.