# Is there a WITH clause in SPARQL?

Tags: sparql

Is there any analog of view creation or WITH clause from SQL in SPARQL?

I want to:

1. Select some data from table;
2. Select data which is not in the first selection (by subject) from the same table.

This seems to work without "WITH" but i do two similar SELECT query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM NAMED <http://...>
{
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o
    WHERE {
      BIND (<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> AS ?p)
      { ?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept> . }
      FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "ru"))
      
    }
    ORDER BY ?o
  }

  UNION
  
  {
    SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o
    WHERE {
      BIND (<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> AS ?p)
      { ?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept> . }
      FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "en"))


      MINUS {  
        SELECT DISTINCT ?s 
        WHERE {
          BIND (<http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#prefLabel> AS ?p)
          { ?s <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#type> <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#Concept> . }
          FILTER(LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "ru"))

        }
      }
    }

    ORDER BY ?o
  }
}
```

Comment: As for `WITH`, it's Blazegraph specific: https://github.com/blazegraph/database/wiki/NamedSubquery. As for negation, there are `NOT EXISTS` and `MINUS`: https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#negation

Comment: @StanislavKralin i've added my query to the answer. It seems to work but i make two similar select in it. Is this the only way?

Comment: Что получить-то хотите? Триплеты с "русским" литералом в объекте, если он есть в исходных данных, и с английским, если нет? Try `CONSTRUCT`. Please also use prefixed forms of URIs, since people use smartphones. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. Also, `?o` is not bound in subqueries.

Answer (score 0):

There is a WITH keyword used in SPARQL Updates. SPARQL Updates use some different keywords compared to queries, but analogous. The WITH keyword "defines the graph that will be modified or matched against for any of the subsequent elements" much like the GRAPH keyword (which may also be used). Additionally, other query keywords transfer to update keywords.

- FROM -> USING
- FROM NAMED -> USING NAMED

The language is essentially different on purpose to reduce confusion between queries and updates.

However, the question is about queries. The given query is not well formed and would be well served by using logical operators and condensing.  As noted, the `?o` variable is unbound and serves no purpose in the original query. Also, the `FROM NAMED` should likely by just `FROM` as the `FROM NAMED` graph is expected to be specified in the WHERE clause in a GRAPH expression.

As a proposed solution, the OP likely wants the following (or a similar CONSTRUCT solution):

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o 
FROM <SomeGraphIRI>
WHERE {
  ?s  a  skos:Concept ;
     ?p  ?o .
  FILTER(
    LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "ru") ||
    ( LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "en") &&
      NOT EXISTS {
        ?s ?p ?o2 .
        FILTER( LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o2), "ru") )
      }
    )
  )
}
ORDER BY ?o
VALUES ?p { skos:prefLabel }
```

OR (see [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56674720/sparql-query-template-with-language-filters))

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
SELECT DISTINCT ?s ?p ?o 
FROM <SomeGraphIRI>
WHERE {
  ?s  a  skos:Concept ;
     ?p  ?o .
  FILTER(
    IF (
      NOT EXISTS {
        ?s ?p ?o2 .
        FILTER( LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o2), "ru") )
      },
      LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "en"),
      LANGMATCHES(LANG(?o), "ru")
    )
  )
}
ORDER BY ?o
VALUES ?p { skos:prefLabel }
```

Adding an implicit `isLiteral(?o)` to the `FILTER`s may also be helpful, but is implied by the `LANG` functions.

YMMV!